# Chosen multiselect order. Plugin active when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, jquery-chosen

I'm not very familiar with jquery, so don't be very strict. Task was to make order in Chosen multiselect plugin. 
Here is workaround:

```
$(function(){
        $("select#Books_id_author").each(function(){
            if($(this).data("order")==true){
                $(this).val('');
                $(this).chosen();
                var $ordered = $('[name="_'+jQuery(this).attr('id')+'"]');
                var selected = $ordered.val().split(',');
                var chosen_object = $(this).data('chosen');
                $.each(selected, function(index, item){
                    $.each(chosen_object.results_data, function(i, data){
                        if(data.value == item){
                            $("#"+data.dom_id).trigger('mouseup');
                        }
                    });
                });
                $(this).data("backupVal",$(this).val());
                $(this).change(function(){
                    var backup = $(this).data("backupVal");
                    var current = $(this).val();
                    if(backup == null){
                        backup = [];
                    }
                    if(current == null){
                        current = [];
                    }
                    if(backup.length > current.length){
                        $.each(backup, function(index, item) {
                            if($.inArray(item, current) < 0){
                                for(var i=0; i<selected.length; i++){
                                    if(selected[i] == item){
                                        selected.splice(i,1);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }else if(backup.length < current.length){
                        $.each(current, function(index, item) {
                            if($.inArray(item, backup) < 0){
                                selected.push(item);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    $ordered.val(selected.join(','));
                    $(this).data("backupVal",current);
                });
            }else{
                $(this).chosen();
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is, that plugin active after page load (i suppose it's because trigger('mouseup')) and showing results drop.

Is there any trigger in Chosen to make it not active, or maybe something another.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by writing order plugin for chosen.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippet, example, or links?